# Android automatically Capture selfie on face detection and display in image view

Tags: android, face-detection

I am developing an android app I want to capture the user's face when activity open and then display that image in the image view. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this article to ask the good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thanks but do you know the answer??

Comment: No, but Google Does.

Comment: I already google when I didn't get the answer  I asked this question. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mobil Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial) to trigger activity for taking pictures when the face detected. And if you want to send it to another activity it would be a real problem because of intents don't send high memory data. You can check it from [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Comment: What if I convert that image into base64 will it be a problem??

Comment: Yes, of course. base64 or not. If intent's memory limit is overloaded, there will be a problem by android OS. The limit approximately 1 MB

Comment: Checkout storing file in android, or use services. It is not concurrent question actually. You can search and find many ways. Good luck